# Swift: Convert ISO8601 to Unix Epoch

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, epoch, iso8601

I'd like to take a ISO8601 timestamp, like this: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`, and convert it to a Unix epoch time stamp using Swift.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the numerous related questions? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873862/date-conversion-and-date-difference-issue-in-swift

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ I did, and I found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ISO8601DateFormatter` converts the string to `Date`, `timeIntervalSince1970` gets the UNIX timestamp.

```
let timestamp = ISO8601DateFormatter().date(from: "2017-07-14T20:00:00Z")!.timeIntervalSince1970
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching all the stackoverflow, I could create a  **working snippet!!**

```
let isoFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    isoFormatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate,.withTime, .withFractionalSeconds,.withDashSeparatorInDate,.withColonSeparatorInTime]
    let date = UInt64((isoFormatter.date(from: "2021-04-14T10:09:10.773Z")?.timeIntervalSince1970 ?? 0) * 1000) // your time here with milliseconds
print(date) // prints 1619706315298
```

Answer (score 0):

- Swift 4 / swift 5

---

here is an **extension**

```
extension String{
func dateToEpoch() -> UInt64 {
    let isoFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
isoFormatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate,.withTime, .withFractionalSeconds,.withDashSeparatorInDate,.withColonSeparatorInTime]
let date = UInt64((isoFormatter.date(from: self)?.timeIntervalSince1970 ?? 0) * 1000)
    return date
}                                                               
}
```

**usage**

```
let epochTime =  "2021-04-14T10:09:10.773Z".dateToEpoch()
print(epochTime)
```

Comment: Does not work for me with the following string `2021-09-20T14:15:22Z` Returns always `0`.